# How do you make transparent elements non-interactable?

Tags: css

I'm showing and hiding elements with a fade in / fade out effect.

**CSS**

```
.element {
   opacity: 1.0;
   transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.element.hidden {
   opacity: 0.0;
}
```

**JS**

```
// hide
$('someElement').addClassName('hidden');

// show
$('someElement').removeClassName('hidden');
```

The problem with this is that an invisible element still occupies space. If the user tries to click something beneath it, this invisible element intercepts the click and the user gets confused. Is there a CSS property that will make the element non-interactable? I'm aware there are some hacks like setting `top:-999em` in the `.hidden` class, but I'm asking if you know any elegant solutions.

Comment: standard practice is to set `display:none;` after fading it out. I'm not sure if simply adding that to `.element.hidden` would suffice, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Shmiddty That is the way to abruptly hide things with JS. If you combine `display:none` with a CSS transition, you will not see a transition at all because the element disappears first and the animation would be applied after it's already disappeared.

Comment: I wasn't sure if `display` was an animatable property. Apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to transition `visibility` as well:

```
.element {
   opacity: 1.0;
   visibility: visible;
   transition: opacity 0.3s linear, visibility 0.3s linear;
}

.element.hidden {
   opacity: 0.0;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

An element with `visibility: hidden` can be clicked through; i.e. it won't intercept the click.

If you need the element to disappear altogether rather than continue to occupy space, you need to use `display: none` instead, but that is not an animatable property so you'll see the element disappear abruptly rather than fade out.